# ng-select doesn't display value in ngModel

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ngselect

```
<ng-select [items]="items$ | async"
            bindLabel="value"
            minTermLength="2"
            bindValue="id"
            [(ngModel)]="val"
            [typeahead]="valInput$">
</ng-select>
```

**ng-select** above does server-side search and until typing something that **items** is empty but the variable **val** is not.
Need to see **val**'s value as selected item but can't achieve that so my guess is the reason for that is items being empty.

Is there a way to display **val** in that ng-select component **even if items is empty**?

**UPDATE:**
I've populated **items$** with existing values. But still can't make them selected.

**UPDATE 2:**
I've found the solution, **bindValue="id"** was the problem and I needed to remove it which means binding the whole object instead of it's id attribute to selected item.